# How to I get the previous h3 value when iterating through a list of found elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the previous h3 content when I iterate over my list?

```
    var statusLabel= $("ul li:contains('Status: MyStatus')");

    for(i = 0; i < statusLabel.length; i++) {
          // How to i get the previous h3 content of each statusLabel
    }
```

Example html hierarchy:

```
<a>
<h3>ToBeExtracted</h3>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
<ul>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the previous h3 element? Show some HTML so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: You will have to show the relevant HTML.

Comment: `jQuery(this).closest('h3')` something like this maybe? But need HTML to help

Comment: `this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jquery you can start a "for each" loop directly on the jquery object like this:

```js
$("ul li:contains('Status: My status')").each(function(i,li){
  console.log('h3:',$(li).closest('ul').prevAll('h3:first').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>ToBeExtracted 1</h3>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
<ul>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
</ul>
<h3>ToBeExtracted 2</h3>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
<ul>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
</ul>  
<h3>ToBeExtracted 3</h3>
<div class="description">A Div in between ...
</div>
<ul>
    <li>and</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>more</li>
    <li>padding</li>
    <li>and</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>more</li>
    <li>padding</li>
</ul>
```

You need to "climb" up to the `<ul>` element first, then look backwards (`.prevAll('h3:first')`) on the same level until you encounter the first `<h3>` element.

---

**Edit:**

Here is a second, more robust Vanilla JS solution that can deal with *any* document structure. It simply looks at the sequence of `<h3>` and `<li>` elements - regardless how they are stacked - and returns the required hits:

```js
var h3,res=[];
[...document.querySelectorAll('h3,li')].forEach(e=>{
 if(e.nodeName=='H3') h3=e;
 if(e.nodeName=='LI' &&
  e.innerText.indexOf('Status: My')>-1) res.push(h3.innerText);
});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<h3>ToBeExtracted 1</h3>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
<div>
  this is a div, encasing the first UL section
  <ul>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
  </ul>
  end of container-div
</div>
<h3>ToBeExtracted 2</h3>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
<ul>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
    <li>some padding</li>
    <li>and some more ...</li>
</ul>  
<h3>ToBeExtracted 3</h3>
<div class="description">A Div in between ...
</div>
<ul>
    <li>and</li>
    <li>Status: My status</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>more</li>
    <li>padding</li>
    <li>and</li>
    <li>some</li>
    <li>more</li>
    <li>padding</li>
</ul>
```